# Pandas new column with calculation based on other existing column

Tags: python, pandas, calculation

I have a Panda and want to do a calculation based on an existing column. 
However, the apply. function is not working for some reason.

It's something like letssay

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Age': age, 'Input': input})
```

and the input column is something like [1.10001, 1.49999, 1.60001]
Now I want to add a new column to the Dataframe, that is doing the following:

- Add 0.0001 to each element in column
- Multiply each value by 10
- Transform each value of new column to int

Comment: What is not working exactly? How do you use df.apply()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html), [`Series.mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mul.html) and [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
#input is python code word (builtin), so better dont use it like variable
inp = [1.10001, 1.49999, 1.60001] 
age = [10,20,30]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Age': age, 'Input': inp})
df['new'] = df['Input'].add(0.0001).mul(10).astype(int)
print (df)
   Age    Input  new
0   10  1.10001   11
1   20  1.49999   15
2   30  1.60001   16
```

Comment: What if input has None or not numeric data, which cause add method to throw error?

Comment: @furkanayd - then first step is create numeric - check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/change-data-type-of-columns-in-pandas)

Answer (score 1):

You could make a simple function and then apply it by row.

```
def f(row):
    return int((row['input']+0.0001)*10))

df['new'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
```

Comment: It is bad practise use [loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas), because exist vectorized solution. (apply are loops under the hood)

Comment: I thought apply was vectorized as well. I am not using iterrows()

Comment: yop, something new for you. apply are loops too. Better like iterrows, but also better avoid it, if exist vectorized solution like here.